# How does $all operator works with $elemMatch in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, operators

please provide an explanation of this MongoDB query.

```
db.inventory.find({ qty : { $all : [ { $elemMatch : { size: "M", num : { $gt : 40},color : "green" }} ,{ $elemMatch : { num :100 , color : "green"}}  ]}}).pretty()
```

Comment: The documentation on both query operators is excellent. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: But this query print documents which satisfy any of the condition specified in $all. What i understand is $all collect documents which satisfy all of the conditions. correct me if i am wrong. For more clarification i can add output fi u say so @AlexP.

Comment: Clarification is always good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so imagine we have the following document:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a148f114d8a2fe38bec772a"),
    "samplearray" : [ 
        {
            "size" : "M",
            "num" : 45,
            "color" : "black"
        }, 
        {
            "size" : "L",
            "num" : 75,
            "color" : "blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here `samplearray` has two entries

## 1

This query:

```
db.sample.find({ samplearray: { $elemMatch: { num: { $gt: 41 }}}})
```

Would return the document. In the query we ask for an array value entry where `num` is greater than 41.

## 2

Now if we do this query:

```
db.sample.find({ samplearray: { $elemMatch: { num: { $gte: 50 }, color: "black"}}})
```

it should not return anything. Because `$elemMatch` looks into each separate array value entry. And now the document doesn't match. Because in a single array we don't have an array value entry that satisfies both conditions. In the document we have an array entry that fulfills the `num: { $gte: 50 }` (example:

```
{
  "size" : "L",
  "num" : 75,
  "color" : "blue"
}
```

)

and one for `color: "black"` (example:

```
{
   "size" : "M",
   "num" : 45,
   "color" : "black"
}
```

)
, but not both in one.

## 3

If we wanted to get the document as result then we would have to rewrite our query and here is where we introduce `$all`:

```
db.sample.find({
    samplearray: {
        $all: [{
                $elemMatch: {
                    num: {
                        $gte: 50
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $elemMatch: {
                    color: "black"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Do you understand now `$all` and `$elemMatch` a little bit better?